# ¿Cómo identificar capítulos sin numerar en un libro?

Tags: r, rstudio

Necesito identificar los cuentos que forman parte de una colección de libros. Cada cuento viene identificado por su título en mayúsculas. Pongo la siguiente expresión en R:

```
   posicion_cuento<- grep("^[[:upper:]]+$", texto)
```

Y de los 12 títulos que hay solo me detecta 3 que son títulos de una palabra, "INAMIBLE" o "IRREDENCIÓN", dejándome fuera títulos como "LAS NIÑAS" o "EL CHIFLÓN DEL DIABLO".

¿Qué puedo hacer para incluir grupos de palabras en mayúsculas?

Answer (score 1):

Las cadenas como `LAS NIÑAS` o `EL CHIFLÓN DEL DIABLO` tienen dos problemas con respecto a tu patrón: (1) los espacios (2) las letras latinas: `Ñ`, `Ó`. Eso claramente no se condice con el patrón que has indicado. Yo lo modificaría por algo así:

```
grepl("^[[:upper:][:space:]ÓÑ]+$", 
      c("HOLA un minuscula", "INAMIBLE", "IRREDENCIÓN",
        "LAS NIÑAS", "EL CHIFLÓN DEL DIABLO"))

[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Obviamente, hay muchos otros caracteres que deberías incorporar al patrón, faltan acentos y tal vez tengas todo tipo símbolos: interrogación, exclamación, puntuación etc. Una opinión personal: cuando empiezas a manejar muchas condiciones especiales para plasmar la idea, suele ser un buen momento para pensar si otro tipo de patrón o directamente otro tipo de solución es más efectivo para resolver el problema.